# ¿Cómo cambiar color dependiendo valor desde otra función en el Plugin de Datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

¿Cómo podría cambiar el color de un dato desde otra función en datatable?

Actualmente ya puedo cambiar el color pero directamente desde :

```
 {
        data: 'Fecha', width: '5%', "sClass": "alinear",
        render: function (data, type) {
            if (type != 'display') return data;

            var FormatDatos = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display;

            return FormatDatos(Math.floor(data / 1000)) ;
        },
        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            if (sData < 0) {
                $(nTd).css('color', 'red')
            }
        }
```

Pero lo que quiero es aplicar el color desde otra función:

```
 function SacarDiferenciaActivoCirculante(data, type, row, meta, adt) {
    var table = $("#tblEstados").DataTable();
    var allData = table.rows().data();
    var FechaEntero = Math.round(row.Fecha);
    var FechaEntero2 = Math.round(row.fecha2);
    var Resultado = FechaEntero2 - FechaEntero;
    var ResultadoRenderNumber = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display(Resultado / 1000);


   return ResultadoRenderNumber

}
```

A la función

> SacarDiferenciaActivoCirculante

La mando a llamar desde:

```
 columnDefs: [
        { "name": "engine", "targets": 0 },
        {targets: [2],render: PrimerPorcentajeCirculante, },
        { targets: [4], render: SegundoPorcentajeCirulante },
        { targets: [5], render: SacarDiferenciaActivoCirculante },
        { targets: [6], render: SacarDiferenciaPorcentajeActivoCirculante },
    ],
```

Asi quiero que sea el Resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día ingeniero.

Usted puede arreglar su problema guardando en una variable el codigo de color y despues en su funcion principal hace el llamado a la variable y a la funcion.

aqui un ejemplo de como sería el guardado de color en funcion aparte:

```
<input type="text" id="texto"><button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button><div id="resultado"></div>
```

y en script:

```
<script>
    function enviar(){
        var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        busca_color(texto);
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "<p style='color: "+colores+";'>"+texto+"</p>";
    }
    function busca_color(texto){
        if(texto == "hola"){
                 colores = "#ff0000";
                }
                else{
                colores = "#1100ff";
                }
        
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @PabloEscalante,Lo que necesito es pintar un dato no mostrar solo el color

Comment: la funcion que tengo en el codigo es pintar el texto cuando se muestre, pero lo fundamental es guardar el codigo del color en una variable y asi en el estilo pintas la variable

Comment: Actualizare la pregunta para que se de una idea

Comment: Listo,Acabo  de actualizar la pregunta para mayor referencia

Comment: si, lo unico que ocupas es en la funcion de SacarDiferencia... es crear una condición para que cuando el valor del numero sea negativo guardas en una variable el color que quieres que se pinte, y ya donde pones "$(nTd).css('color', 'red')" solo cambias el color directo por la variable que ya debes de traer